Having a problem understanding the concept of matrix multplication in 3D
From 3b1b's video, "Three dimensional linear transformations| Chapter 5: The essence of linear Algebra", He gives a question for us to do in the end.
A = $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 & 2 \\ 5 & 1 & 5  \\ 1 & 4 & -1  \end{bmatrix}$$
and B = $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 & 5  \\ 6 & 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$$
We have to compute A*B.
I am interested in doing it in the conceptual manner (as he explains in the video) , not the rote method that I have been taught.
So I first assume that B is the first transformation and the A is the second one. Hence, the basis vector is transformed via B to become {0,3,6). And then if I were to transform this (0,3,6) on the basis of the transformation A, I would have to multiply
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 & 2 \\ 5 & 1 & 5  \\ 1 & 4 & -1  \end{bmatrix}$$
with $$\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 3   \\ 6   \end{bmatrix}$$
This results in $$\begin{bmatrix} 6  \\ 33   \\ 6   \end{bmatrix}$$
Which will be the first column in the final product matrix. On verifying with my rote method and the matrix calculator, this is the correct answer.
Now for the second column, I did the exact same thing, multiplying
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 & 2 \\ 5 & 1 & 5  \\ 1 & 4 & -1  \end{bmatrix}$$
with
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 4   \\ 7   \end{bmatrix}$$
This results in
$$\begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 12   \\ 42   \end{bmatrix}$$
as 1(0) + 1(5) + 1(1) = 6
and 4(-2)+ 4(1) + 4(4) = 12          [16+4-8]
and 7(2)+7(5)+ 7(-1) = 42
However
The answer I get through the rote method and the matrix calc is that the second column of the resulting matrix should be
$$\begin{bmatrix} 6  \\ 44   \\ 10   \end{bmatrix}$$
How can this be? The calculations all check out, so I assume I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how these transformations work and what I am supposed to multiply. Can someone clarify my doubts?

Matrix multiplication is row times column https://www.cairographics.org/cookbook/matrix_transform/matrix_multiplication.gif your second calculation is wrong

You're adding in the wrong dimension. To get the first value of the resulting vector, you should multiply a matrix row by a column vector, that is (for the second element in the resulting vector):
$$
[5, 1, 5][1, 4, 7]^T = 5\cdot1+1\cdot4+5\cdot7 = 5+4+35=44.
$$
